# Simple cardinal arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, exponentiation, cardinals

How can I see that $$2^{2^\lambda}>2^\lambda$$ ? Is it used here that $\lambda \geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ ?
The reference is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.06198.pdf), pages 4 and 8.

Comment: $2^\kappa>\kappa$ for any cardinal $\kappa$. Now put $\kappa=2^\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set of cardinality $2^\lambda$, then there is no bijection between $X$ and its powerset; that is, $2^{2^\lambda}=2^{|X|}>|X|=2^\lambda$ by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem). This holds for any cardinal $\lambda$.